# jquery sidebar putting next to each other

Tags: hover, delay, sidebar

I have put together a sidebar with hover-delay animation, but I can't seem to exactly copy the column to place next to the first. This is my first problem.
The second is that I would like to use the jspanel plugin, so that a dragable window will pop up when I click on a sub-item in the sidebar.

I hope this can be brought to a working state.
Thank you very much for responses in advance!

Here's [a link] (http://jsfiddle.net/chrisoutwright/tc4d9t6d/)!

```
$('#categories').corner("top keep");
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#foo").click(function(){
 $().jsPanel().show();
 });
 });


$( "#navigation ul.sub-level" ).corner("").css( "border", "3px double blue" );

jQuery.fn.hoverWithDelay = function(inCallback,outCallback,delay) {
    this.each(function() {
        var timer, $this = this;
        $(this).hover(function(){
           timer = setTimeout(function(){
              timer = null;
              inCallback.call($this);
           }, delay);
        },function() {
           if (timer) {
              clearTimeout(timer);
              timer = null;
           } else
              outCallback.call($this);
        });
    });
};

var hovering = {mainMenu: false, categories: false};

function closeSubMenus() {
    $('ul.sub-level').css('display', 'none');        
}
closeSubMenus();

function closeMenuIfOut() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (!hovering.mainMenu && !hovering.categories) {
            $('#navigation').fadeOut('fast',closeSubMenus);
        }
    },100);       
}

$('ul.top-level li').hoverWithDelay(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('ul').fadeOut('fast', closeMenuIfOut);
}, 500);

$('#categories').hoverWithDelay(function() {
        $('#navigation').show();
        hovering.categories = true;
    },
    function(){
        hovering.categories = false;
        closeMenuIfOut();
    },500);

$('#navigation').hover(function() {
        hovering.mainMenu = true;
    }, function() {
        hovering.mainMenu = false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see at least one error in line 4 where you try to generate/open the jsPanel.

Which jsPanel version do you use? Version 1.x or Version 2.x? The two versions differ on how to use the jsPanel() command.

- version 1.x: $( selector ).jsPanel( config );
- version 2.x: $.jsPanel( config );

Do you get any error messages?